# How to save value of array to localStorage in function?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to save the value of the input into the local storage upon button click.

```js
allNames = []

function submit() {
  let names = document.getElementById("names").value;
  allNames.push(names);

  localStorage.setItem("totalNames", JSON.stringify(allNames))
  console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("totalNames")))

}
```

```html
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>

<input id="names" placeholder="Enter Name">
```

I want to save the value of the name the user enters into the input to local storage so even after the page refreshes, the name will be saved.

Comment: what isnt working?

Comment: Every time I refresh the page, the local storage is cleared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are re-initialing the array every time and then saving into the LS;instead

you should check if there is previuos value in LS and assign to `allnames` if exist like this

```js
let allNames;

if(localStorage.getItem("totalNames")){
 allNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("totalNames"))
}else{
 allNames= []
}
```